# Using Green's theorem find line integral $\oint_C (-x^2+x) dy $ enclosed by $x=2y^2$ and $y=2x$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

> Using Green's theorem find line integral $\oint_C (-x^2+x)\, dy $ enclosed by $x=2y^2$ and $y=2x$

The intersection points between the line and the parabola are

$$P_1 = \left( 0,0 \right) \quad P_2 = \left( \frac{1}{8} , \frac{1}{4} \right)$$

That said, knowing that

$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = -2x+1 \quad \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = 0 \qquad \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial P}{\partial y} = -2x+1$$

So

$$\oint_C (-x^2+x)\, dy  = \int_{0}^{\frac{1}{4}} \int_{2y^2}^{\frac{y}{2}} \left( -2x + 1 \right) \, dxdy = \cdots = \frac{3}{640}$$

The answer of the textbook is different.

[image]

**Textbook's answer:** $\frac{1}{5}$

Did I make a mistake somewhere?

Comment: I can't spot any mistake in what you did...but for the typo in the middle line. Are you sure **all** the data is correct? Maybe you read the solution to *another* question?

Comment: Hi Don, yes I am sure, I'll insert the question so that you may see it. Thank you.

Comment: Then that seems to be a mistake in the solutions part: I just did the line integral by definition and I  got $\;\cfrac3{640}\;$ again...

Comment: Thank you Don, I am getting the same also. Did you see that I inserted the question from the book?

Comment: @br Yes, I saw. In portuguese.

Comment: Yes! Ok Don, I appreciate your help, best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You changed $-2x-1$ to $-2x+1$ in your last integral.

Comment: But $-2x + 1$ is correct for the rotation I think.

Comment: That's just a typo the OP made in the rightmost expression in the middle. It should be $\;\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial P}{\partial y}=-2x+1\;$ . Yet he wrote the right expression one line below.

Comment: Thank you for spoting the typos, I actually made the calculations with the right expression nevertheless.

Comment: Um...the question was "did I make a mistake somewhere?"  Showing the mistake is _exactly_ the answer to the question.